# Android - Delete entire ImageSpan when part of it is deleted?

Tags: android, image, android-edittext

I'm adding an image to my edittext by inserting an ImageSpan. I don't have a thorough understanding of spans but it seems that my ImageSpan needs to wrap a portion of text. So I add some text to the EditText, and wrap it with my ImageSpan and it appears fine. However, when I backspace the ImageSpan, it only deletes one character of the text and the image remains until the entire text is delete. How do I get it to just delete with one backspace?

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append(content.getText());

String imgId = "[some useful text]"; 

int selStart = content.getSelectionStart();

builder.replace(content.getSelectionStart(), content.getSelectionEnd(), imgId);

builder.setSpan(imageSpan, selStart, selStart+imgId.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
content.setText(builder);
```

Comment: it should remive the span after the first backspace, what os version are you using?

Answer (score 7):

After some time, I found solution. Try this code:

```
private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    private int spanLength = -1;

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        if (start == 0) return;
        if (count > after) {
            ImageSpan[] spans = getEditableText().getSpans(start + count, start + count, ImageSpan.class);
            if (spans == null || spans.length == 0) return;
            for (int i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
                int end = getEditableText().getSpanEnd(spans[i]);
                if (end != start + count) continue;
                String text = spans[i].getSource();
                spanLength = text.length() - 1;
                getEditableText().removeSpan(spans[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (spanLength > -1) {
            int length = spanLength;
            spanLength = -1;
            getEditableText().replace(start - length, start, "");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
```

But you should create ImageStan with original String like this:

```
ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmpDrawable, originalStr), x, x + originalStr.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Well, doesn't work on every device.. Can you please check my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942628/delete-entire-imagespan-when-the-part-of-it-is-deleted

Answer (score 1):

Here's my stab on it:

```
field.doBeforeTextChanged { text, start, count, _ ->
            val spans = toField.text.getSpans<ImageSpan>(start = start + 1, end = start + 1 + count)
            for (span in spans) {
                toField.text.removeSpan(span)
            }
        }
```

Don't forget to replace `ImageSpan` with the one you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are useful. But be careful that: `imagespan.source` is used to save information about the image **uri** when you construct it!
when you use `ImageSpan`, `mSource` is given the string value of the drawable resource connected to its `uri`
Use `contentDescription` instead in **Api 30** and above
or do like this may help

```
private val watcher: TextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        if(s.isEmpty()) return
        // delete operation
        // from position 'start'
        // the tail of 's',with length 'count' would be erased 
        // for ime input reason, 'count' is always 1
        if(count>after){
            val spans: Array<ImageSpan> = article_publish_content.text.getSpans(
                0, start + count,
                ImageSpan::class.java
            )
            if (spans.isEmpty()) return
            // here sometimes you could use spans[spans.indices-1]
            // to reduce no-need traversal
            for (i in spans.indices) {
                val spanEnd: Int = article_publish_content.text.getSpanEnd(spans[i])
                val spanStart=article_publish_content.text.getSpanStart(spans[i])
                if (spanEnd != start + count) continue
                spanLength = spanEnd-spanStart
                article_publish_content.text.removeSpan(spans[i])
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        if (spanLength > -1) {
            val length = spanLength
            spanLength = -1
            var oStart=start-length
            if(oStart<0)
                oStart=0
            article_publish_content.text.replace(oStart, start, "")
        }
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {

    }
}
```